# Blue spots in omelette?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, omelette

My sister made me an omelette earlier, and when I dug into it I noticed several blue spots inside it, resembling mold or dye. It tasted perfectly fine, but just looked odd. She assured me that they didn't look like that whilst they were raw, but I threw the rest away to be on the safe side. What could this have been?

Comment: did she put pepper in it? How large were the spots?

Comment: Wondering if she used a metal spatula and it’s little specks of the metal pan.

Comment: Could you include the include the ingredient list?

Comment: I assume you didn't fill it with blue cheese, or you would have said. But what was the source of the eggs? I get mine from a home flock and some of those hens lay eggs with blue shells. Is there anything of that shade of blue in the kitchen - shreds of packaging for example?

Comment: Ask her to do it again, and take a picture!

Comment: A blue plastic spatula or whisk maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the yolk was overcooked in an iron pan. Hydrogen sulfide + Iron = Hydrogen and Iron Sulfide (which is dark blue to black). This is a common reaction in eggs and generally is not dangerous at all. You can even see it in hard-boiled eggs when the yolk turns a little bit green. The most dangerous thing about this might be the hydrogen which is created in the process.